# In which way my question was off-topic

Tags: support, off-topic

I posted a question a few days ago about VirtualHost in Apache on CentOS server: [My post here](https://serverfault.com/questions/667661/change-to-documentroot-for-virtualhost-in-httpd-conf-dont-take-effect-in-web-bro?noredirect=1#comment818187_667661)

This question was flagged off-topic: "Administration panels are off topic.".  In any ways my question is about administrative panel, In my effort to describe how I've created the problem I got to use the write about WHM panel, but the problem I got is about VirtualHost config via terminal, and there is the topic of my question.

Could you please, remove the off-topic flag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't hold my breath.  It took a fair bit of effort to get administration panels explicitly put into list of forbidden topic on here, and they are off topic.  Not that having an administration panel is only reason your question's off topic, mind you.

The bigger issue with your question, which can't be fixed is that your problem wasn't a systems administration problem, ***it was a typing problem***.  You say, yourself:

> OK, I'm a bit confuse, but it worked all that time; I mismatched 2 public folders one over the other, Lol.

So, the problem was you made a typo, and you want that question reopened?

Hell no.

Comment: why are administration panels off-topic?

Comment: @warren Web panels are not system administration, they are using a web app. This also refers http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6538/is-it-time-to-kill-problematic-tags-like-cpanel-plesk-whm-and-webmin

Comment: @warren Because it says they are in the on-topic help guide. And what Iain said. How to click into the hostname field on a LAMP administration panel and type in your webserver's desired hostname is in no way system administration. By even allowing these questions to be asked and answered, we just invite more crappy questions about *"halp i got a vps and i don't know how to server, plz to be explain the cpanel 2 me kthx bai"*, to the point that we literally have many thousands of this type of question, and the general consensus among the community is that we can't kill them fast enough.

Comment: To further clarify, questions must provide value to future users. Problems that are specific to the point of not applying to others in the future is not a useful question by Stack Exchange standards. The question might not get closed if there were some particularly heroic (and applicable) answers that were submitted if they could help others, but this is not one of those cases.