# Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?

Tags: discussion, faq, off-topic, allowed-topics

My question was closed as off-topic because it is "about a web hosting control panel". But I still need help. Where can I ask my question?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Unfortunately Server Fault is [unable to support web hosting control panels for a variety of reasons](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/8055/126632). But you may still be able to get help at:

## Your Service Provider

If you are using a web hosting resource (e.g. shared hosting or VPS) provided by someone else and need help with the control panels to manage it, first contact your service provider. If the service provider is unable or unwilling to help, continue on:

## Vendor Support

Generally you should first seek support from the vendor of your control panel. They know their products best and will be able to give you the most appropriate help. The support pages of the most popular control panels are available:

[cPanel/WHM](https://cpanel.com/support/)

[DirectAdmin](https://www.directadmin.com/support.html)

[ISPConfig](http://www.ispconfig.org/support/)

[Kloxo/HyperVM](http://lxcenter.org/get-support)

[Plesk](https://www.plesk.com/support/)

[Sentora](http://www.sentora.org/support)

[ServerPilot](https://serverpilot.io/support.html)

[VestaCP](https://vestacp.com/support/)

[Virtualmin](https://www.virtualmin.com/support)

[ZPanel](http://www.zpanelcp.com/support/)

## Stack Exchange

Some Stack Exchange sites may also be able to help you with your question.

[Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) may be able to help you with questions about running your website.

[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) may be able to help with questions about Linux and Linux applications.

## Web Hosting Industry

There may be other forums and community resources you can visit. A small sampling of these follows:

[Digital Point Forums](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/) has a [Site & Server Administration](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/forums/site-server-administration.18/) section.

[Web Hosting Talk](https://www.webhostingtalk.com/) has a [Hosting Software and Control Panels](https://www.webhostingtalk.com/forumdisplay.php?f=9) section.

Comment: Before you ask: Webmin is _not_ a web hosting control panel, so it is not included here. Its extension Virtualmin, however, _is_.

Comment: Why webmin it's not a control panel? Because it's opensource? The objective of webmin is the same as that of a control panel. It is to provide a web interface to the administrator. And also has its own forum.

Comment: @abkrim Webmin (alone) is not designed for _hosting web sites_. That's Virtualmin.

Comment: that it's your opinion. Webmin its perfect for hosting. If you know system Webmin it's perfect. On a scale of 0 to 10 on usability for hosting panel, webmin would be a Virtualmin 1 and 3. Both panels are very poor facilities, but suficinetes for the same purpose.

Comment: @abkrim So we should also ban questions about Webmin, then?

Comment: For purists if. Now, of all panels on the list in tens of thousands of questions and hundreds of thousands of responses. It's curious.

Comment: I know nothing about cpanel, exept that I used a cpanel host in my young time, but a quicksearch on webhostingtalk.com (a reference for me for webhosting) return a lot of query about webmin used as plesk or cpanel. It can be a good discussion to have if we add that tool to the list.

Comment: @yagmoth555 My understanding is that Webmin just does general system administration (via a web interface), and that web hosting is done by its addon Virtualmin (which you don't have to use). I could be wrong about this, or people could be trying to do web hosting with Webmin alone (which strikes me as doubly insane)...

Comment: ah ok! thanks for the clarification about the addon. I now suspect then the post I seen told webmin term, but would use virtualmin in the final, would make more sense.

Comment: Different cases are and should be threaten very differently. Say: bind9 issue on ISPConfig. It's not an ISPConfig related issue, as it just produces raw bind9 files in the etc directory, if the asker provides full bind9 confs, there's no need to threat it as an ISPConfig related issue. Just cause the asker wrote "ISPConfig" in the question. If he didn't, then the same question would be threaten differently. That's stupid. https://serverfault.com/questions/807050/bind9-will-not-serve-txt-records-for-some-domains-and-will-serve-it-for-others

Answer (score 2):

What is the use of StackExchange forum or site, when we have to go to vendors or service providers to resolve our issues? If system admins or the vendors themselves want to ask a question about system admin, it means this site is useless for them?

It is a really stupid decision.

Comment: Sometimes, going to the vendor is the correct thing to do. This is true of the WHM/cPanel support questions.

Comment: cpanel is a special case. as we support what lies underneath, not the tool that customize the whole system over the other tools. not to forget that usually we would help cpanel user, not the server admin, as usually the admin got a support contract and would just reformat the box in case of a trouble. so as iain told, in must cpanel issue it would end up in cpanel support anyhow, as a customized tool, giving advice for the beneath tool could make more damage than anything.

Comment: Seems like for Every technology, we should always contact the vendors, or the product developers. so whats the use of serverfault? (stackexchange) i think it kills the purpose of building such websites where  ppl can get help, when they cannot get help from anyone else.. also when they ask complicated questions, other people benefit from them as well.
If everyone solve their issues by Vendors, then would there be Any use of stackexchange? i think no. so its better to shut this site down for good
@Hanginoninquietdesperation

Comment: @yagmoth555 : how is anyone suppose to make sure that every question that comes,its Precisely only related to cPanel? it could be any other issue, just because its based on cPanel,it means no one should touch any question related to it ? how does it makes any sense?

Comment: @Farhan [I want to say these should be left open, but these panels muck about so much with the system that, unless one is a frequent cPanel user (which none of the SF "Answerers" are), it's impossible to know what exactly cPanel is managing and what it's leaving alone.](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/8056/218888)

Comment: i agree, but there are hundreds of )probably thousands) of cases, where it Not the cPanel or any WHM... so you mean to say if that is the case, serverfault should be banned to be used for those issues? or such issues should be denied that they dont exist?

Comment: @Farhan to put it in context, when cpanel question got called offtopic, a lot, lot of cpanel question was unanswered. As Reace mention it, it scramble the system and it's really hard to answer in SE style (question/direct answer). The best option if someday you want cpanel question back would be to have like cpanel's support watch the cpanel's tag to help out. (as like Microsoft do with the internet-explorer tag on SO)

Comment: @Farhan What I'm saying is that unless you are very proficient in troubleshooting cPanel, the issue is likely clouded by the fact that cPanel changes so much about the core system. As such it is usually / nearly always much faster to contact cPanel support. And if you are a professional sysadmin with a licensed cPanel instance, you should have access to their support.

Comment: @Farhan `Spiceworks` for the win

Comment: @lain: you are right, you said "sometimes" not Always good.
so Sometime we should go and ask from other sources too. venders are not always reliable and provide all solutions