# Is IIS exempt from the ban on "web control panel" questions?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I was looking at the reasons for closing some questions as off topic and I was wondering why the Microsoft web hosting technology IIS was exempt from the list as mentioned in the answer to [this](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8094/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels) question.

Have I misunderstood or is it just an oversight?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IIS is a web server like Apache, which happens to have a 1st party GUI control panel to control the web server. This is not at all comparable to cPanel etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification