# Is Spam Assassin via CPanel configuration on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Over at SuperUser meta, they reckoned that [my question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13341/is-spam-assasin-configuration-on-topic?noredirect=1#comment37364_13341) belongs here.

Personally, I am not so sure, but thought that I would ask.

To quote:

> My web host company handles my email & they run it through Apache Spam
>   Assasin.
>
> Using CPanel, I only see options to black/white-list domains, but I
>   would like to mark as spam based on certain words in the email
>   subject.
>
> Is it on-topic to ask on this site how to do so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope.

Questins involving CPanel (and other web control panels) are not topical on Serverfault. There is an explicit off topic close reason for them

> Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic at Server Fault because they customize their systems such that normal administration tools and methods no longer apply, and thus require support from the vendor or the web hosting industry. See Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?

Comment: Also note that  questions regarding  general web hosting services are also off-topic because you are not the actual admin of those systems.

Comment: Thank you very much for the expected answer. I will point it as the SuperUser meta and see whether I can post there.

Comment: @Mawg Here is the link for: [Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8094/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels). Also see the CPanel link in the Vendor section of the answer.