# Are questions asking about reading metadata business questions?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, on-topic

I'm not sure if my question is applicable to business environment, as required in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). Can you check and see if it's on-topic here? Below is my draft.

---

> ## What makes Open Graph checkers unable to detect Open Graph data?
>
> [My page](https://lyminhnhat.com/resources/productivity/recommended-software/?utm_source=SE%3A%20ServerFault&utm_medium=Recommended%20software&utm_campaign=Getting%20help&utm_term=post%3A%20Why%20can't%20Open%20Graph%20checker%20detect%20Open%20Graph%20data%3F), after adding SSL certificate, cannot have preview fetched by Facebook or Twitter when sharing the link. I have followed [The Open Graph protocol](https://opengraphprotocol.org/) and include the following open graph tags:
>
> ```
> <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
> <meta property="og:title" content="Corner Timer: gently make you feel guilty on time-wasting apps" />
> <meta property="og:url" content="https://lyminhnhat.com/resources/productivity/corner-timer-gently-make-you-feel-guilty-on-time-wasting-apps/" />
> <meta property="og:description" content="Make you feel guilty for your unproductive curiosity" />
> <meta name="twitter:site" content="@ooker777" />
> <meta name="twitter:text:title" content="Corner Timer: gently make you feel guilty on time-wasting apps" />
> <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://lyminhnhat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Screenshot_2019-04-11-11-31-39.png?w=640" />
> <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
> ```
>
> However, all 3 Open Graph checkers I use -
>   [OpenGraphCheck.com](https://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fqu%E1%BA%A3c%E1%BA%A7u.com%2Fbo-suu-tap-tu-dien-chuyen-nganh%2F), [Abhinay Rathore's Open Graph
>   Tester](http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/open-graph-tester/), [Facebook's Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fqu%E1%BA%A3c%E1%BA%A7u.com%2Fbo-suu-tap-tu-dien-chuyen-nganh%2F) - say that there is no Open Graph implement. There is one exception though: [Iframely's Embed Codes](http://debug.iframely.com/)
>
> Since all three checkers have problem with this, probably this is not just a problem of of Facebook, as suggested in [FB OpenGraph og:image not pulling images (possibly
>   https?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8855361/3416774). Nevertheless, nothing changes even though I have tried using html links only, stripping end white space, using `<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">`.
>
> [This person](https://www.reddit.com/r/SEO/comments/csjgav/why_cant_open_graph_checkers_detect_open_graph/) suggests that this may be a server issue. A misconfiguration, perhaps. Do you know why this happens or how to identify the problem?
>
> Other information:
>
> - SSL certificate: Let's Encrypt
> - Control Panel: DirectAdmin
> - Server: Nginx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question would be rejected for being about a server running DirectAdmin, a web hosting control panel. See [Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/8094/126632) for further information about that.

If you can reproduce the problem on a standard server which does not use a web hosting control panel, and can show that it is not a problem with the HTML but rather a server configuration issue, then it would be fine here.

If your question actually is about a problem with the HTML comprising Open Graph metadata, you should ask on our sister site [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). At least, you should rule out a problem with the HTML before coming here.

Comment: thank for your reply. I have checked everything and conclude that the problem should not be about HTML. (I still leave a room that I'm wrong.) So the question is: [how to know if a problem is a server issue or control panel issue?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/124684/52079)

Comment: In the end I ask this question: [Curl returns SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL even though the certificate is correct](https://serverfault.com/q/979938/536315)