# Web Hosting Control Panel questions migration

Tags: discussion, migration

I wanted to share that we got contacted back by [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) for cPanel/WHC question that are off-topic there on ServerFault, that they will gladly accept them.

I just wanted to share it as if you think it's worth moving you can flag it for a move without problem.

nb, It reflect Michael's answer there too; https://meta.serverfault.com/a/6541/256639

Thanks !

Comment: The featured tag displays this on the main page for better visibility. You can remove it again in a week or two.

Comment: Thanks @Sven ! it's good to know and a great idea

Comment: Can we have the migrate/close choices updated to reflect this?

Comment: @chicks: The number of migration targets we have has a hard limit. Adding webmaster would mean to remove others and I believe those are more important.

Comment: I didn't know about the limit, so we're supposed to request a non-menu'd migration.  That works.  Yet the text for the close choice for this points to an old answer on meta.  There's nothing there to indicate that these should be migrated before being closed.  People that miss this thread are not going to have any crumb to work with.

Comment: Do we have / do we want a canonical answer here?

Comment: @chicks I agree that in the closure windows it should be maybe rewrite a bit to reflect that, lets create another meta topic for that. I'am on the road currently, but will try to start the discussion tonight

Comment: https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9469/can-we-have-better-messaging-for-handling-web-hosting-control-panel-questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know. I will start sending people in that direction when they have questions about running their web site.

Answer (score 5):

I have updated the tag descriptions for [cpanel](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cpanel),  [virtualmin](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtualmin) and [plesk](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/plesk) accordingly.