# Can we have better messaging for handling Web Hosting Control Panel questions?

Tags: discussion, migration

In the comments for [this meta question](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9463/web-hosting-control-panel-questions-migration?noredirect=1#comment22621_9463) we noticed that the messaging around closing Web Hosting Control Panel questions is outdated.  The current text is:

> Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic at Server Fault because they [customize their systems such that normal administration tools and methods no longer apply](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/what-should-server-fault-do-with-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels), and thus require support from the vendor or the web hosting industry. See [Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8094/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels)?

This doesn't reflect the new opportunity of transferring these questions to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ .  Also, we won't be able to add this as a migration option because we're at the limit for migration choices.

How should this text be updated or moved?

Comment: There is also a length limit for the custom close reason, though I don't recall offhand what it is exactly I think this one is very close to it.

Comment: We can't just change it to "Your question mentions a web hosting control panel, which you should stop using"? 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this?

> Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic because they [customize their systems so that standard system administration methods no longer apply](//meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055).  Some related topics  may be asked on 
>   [Webmasters](//s.tk/webmasters) or see [Where can I ask questions about web hosting
>   control panels?](//meta.serverfault.com/questions/8094)

17 characters left :)

Comment: Getting rid of "thus require support from the vendor" is a good move.  What if the last sentence started with "Consider moving this to Webmasters or see..."?

Comment: @chicks I prefer the term ´may be asked’ than moving, as we can’t migrate everything too, as each site try to close bad question, not move them. (there is a MSE policy to ´not migrate crap’) It’s like the close reason we have that talk superuser, it’s state ´may be asked on’, as such the community choosed to close the question and not vote to move, and leave the OP the choice to reask on the correct site

Comment: That makes sense.  I don't see any way to make this better.

Comment: I've added this close reason. Please go [remove the old reason and approve the new one](https://serverfault.com/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic).

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Done.

Answer (score 4):

If it fit in length, I would suggest that message;

> Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic because
>   they [customize their systems such that normal administration tools
>   and methods no longer apply](//meta.serverfault.com/q/8055), and thus
>   require support from the vendor. They may be asked on
>   [Webmasters](//s.tk/webmasters) or see [Where can I ask questions
>   about web hosting control panels?](//meta.serverfault.com/q/8094)

Source:

`Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic because they [customize their systems such that normal administration tools and methods no longer apply](//meta.serverfault.com/q/8055), and thus require support from the vendor. They may be asked on [Webmasters](//s.tk/webmasters) or see [Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?](//meta.serverfault.com/q/8094)`

It get the goal of talking about webmaster and it keep both meta post linked, as they give a lot of good informations.

Comment: Too long by 60 characters :( [SE] needs its own URL shortener (edit: they have one, it's just useless (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109877/how-do-we-get-a-new-s-tk-added/301751#301751))

Comment: @Sven oops, I will update with another way to write the link then, it seem better now, less than 400. credit to Glorfindel, but had to stripe the On Server Fault in the first sentance.

Comment: Thinking about it, this is quite contradictory. "We can't help you because it requires support by the vendor, or you could ask on this non-vendor site instead"....

Comment: BTW: I just learned about the `//` syntax for abbreviated URLS. Never heard of it before. Neat!

Comment: @Sven I didnt though to that, yes I agree it can be seen contradictory, +1 for your answer, more consistant :)